# Python. Удаление дублей в двумерном массиве

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется массив из которого нужно удалить строки с одинаковыми uuid, я попробовал создать новый массив и добавлять в него только новые которых еще нет в новом массиве но что то пошло не по плану

```
arr = [['-1', '2021-04-23 23:01:47,656', 'f036fa57-3b83-4d56-889f-e1a02b052d3b'],
       ['2', '2021-04-23 22:54:28,527', 'ac09eb08-07cc-42d9-9656-7f6160adfe18'],
       ['-1', '2021-04-23 22:51:18,321', '337936c0-df17-45e8-aebc-2ea7ad09dfba'],
       ['1', '2021-04-23 22:51:17,232', '337936c0-df17-45e8-aebc-2ea7ad09dfba'],
       ['1', '2021-04-23 22:48:50,076', 'c228295a-cade-467c-961e-e81b33f98fcd']]

newarr = ['','','']
for i in arr:
    if i[2] not in newarr:
        newarr.append(i)

for j in newarr:
    print(j)
```

Вывод

```
['-1', '2021-04-23 23:01:47,656', 'f036fa57-3b83-4d56-889f-e1a02b052d3b']
['2', '2021-04-23 22:54:28,527', 'ac09eb08-07cc-42d9-9656-7f6160adfe18']
['-1', '2021-04-23 22:51:18,321', '337936c0-df17-45e8-aebc-2ea7ad09dfba']
['1', '2021-04-23 22:51:17,232', '337936c0-df17-45e8-aebc-2ea7ad09dfba']
['1', '2021-04-23 22:48:50,076', 'c228295a-cade-467c-961e-e81b33f98fcd']
```

Что я делаю ни так?

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, что именно пошло не по плану и что такое `uuid`.

Comment: дубли остались (3 и 4 строка), uuid это 3 столбец

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так, например:

```py
arr = [
    ['-1', '2021-04-23 23:01:47,656', 'f036fa57-3b83-4d56-889f-e1a02b052d3b'],
    ['2', '2021-04-23 22:54:28,527', 'ac09eb08-07cc-42d9-9656-7f6160adfe18'],
    ['-1', '2021-04-23 22:51:18,321', '337936c0-df17-45e8-aebc-2ea7ad09dfba'],
    ['1', '2021-04-23 22:51:17,232', '337936c0-df17-45e8-aebc-2ea7ad09dfba'],
    ['1', '2021-04-23 22:48:50,076', 'c228295a-cade-467c-961e-e81b33f98fcd'],
]

added = set()
new_arr = []
for el in arr:
    if el[2] not in added:
        new_arr.append(el)
        added.add(el[2])

print(*new_arr, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Имхо - решение с вложенным циклом будет оптимальней чем со временным массивом, хотя зависит от того что экономить :)

Answer (score 1):

Что не так: ты проверяешь наличие одного элемента вложенного списка в списке списков. Образно говоря, не равняется ли буква "и" слову "питон". Нет, не равняется, хоть слово "питон"и содержит букву "и".

Answer (score 0):

Из массива надо удалить все строки с одинаковым третьим элементом ('uuid')? Или одну строку оставить? Если одну оставить, то какую? Если любую, то это можно решить так:

- создаём словарь, в качестве keys которого используем 'uuid', таким образом отфильтровываются повторы 'uuid'
- конвертируем values словаря обратно в list

```
new_dict = {x[2]:x for x in arr}
new_arr = list(new_dict.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [
    ['-1', '2021-04-23 23:01:47,656', 'f036fa57-3b83-4d56-889f-e1a02b052d3b'],
    ['2', '2021-04-23 22:54:28,527', 'ac09eb08-07cc-42d9-9656-7f6160adfe18'],
    ['-1', '2021-04-23 22:51:18,321', '337936c0-df17-45e8-aebc-2ea7ad09dfba'],
    ['1', '2021-04-23 22:51:17,232', '337936c0-df17-45e8-aebc-2ea7ad09dfba'],
    ['1', '2021-04-23 22:48:50,076', 'c228295a-cade-467c-961e-e81b33f98fcd'],
]

uuids = []  # тут будет список уникальных идентификаторов
result = [] # тут будет результат
for row in arr:
    if row[2] not in uuids:  # проверяем, нет ли в списке идентификатора
        result.append(row)   # добавляем в результат всю строку
        uuids.append(row[2]) # в список добавляем только(!) идентификатор

[print(row) for row in result] # вывод результата
```

ошибка была в том, что идентификатор искался в списке строк тут:

```
if el[2]/* это строка */ not in added /* а это список списков(!) */
```

поэтому условие всегда выполнялось - строка среди списков не находилась никак